# Find-Replace pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a complex situation where I need to parse a very long string. I have to look for a pattern in the string and replace that pattern with another. I know I can simply use `find/replace` method but my case is bit different.

I have a string that contains the following pattern

```
#EPB_IMG#index-1_1.jpg#EPB_IMG


#EPB_IMG#index-1_2.jpg#EPB_IMG


#EPB_IMG#index-1_3.jpg#EPB_IMG


#EPB_IMG#index-1_4.jpg#EPB_IMG
```

and I want it to format as

```
#EPB_IMG#index-1_1.jpg|index-1_2.jpg|index-1_3.jpg|index-1_4.jpg#EPB_IMG
```

I don't know much about `Regex` and seeking for help.

Comment: I'd suggest removing "Regex" from the title of this question. It supposes an answer that may not be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is overkill:

```
var parts = s.Split(new string[] { "#EPB_IMG", "#", "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = string.Join("|", parts);

Console.WriteLine("#EPB_IMG#" + result + "#EPB_IMG"); // prints your result.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Expression: `\w+#(?<Image>(.+)\.jpg)#\w+`

Replacement: `${Image}`

Result: `string.Format("#EPB_IMG#{0}#EPB_IMG", string.Join("|", listOfMatches))`

---

**NOTE:**
Regex tested with: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Result is untested, but should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "#EPB_IMG" + Regex.Matches(inputString, @"#EPB_IMG(.+)#EPB_IMG")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
               .Aggregate((f, f2) => f + "|" + f2) + "#EPB_IMG";
```